# System.Web.MVC.SelectList how to set selected item upon creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

trying to have an item in a DropDownList selected by default from within my viewmodel.

I am creating the select list in my view model using teh following overload..

```
public SelectList ProgramsSelectList() 
    {
        var ddlist = new SelectList(DiversionPrograms, "DiversionProgramID", "CrimeName", new {value = "1"});
        return ddlist;
    }
```

value = 1 is just hard coded for now. I am not sure the Html.DropDownList() respects this selected item.

Razor View:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("programSelect", Model.ProgramsSelectList(), "Choose a Program to Manage")
```

I must be missing something here...

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out...

```
var ddlist = new SelectList(DiversionPrograms, "DiversionProgramID", "CrimeName", DiversionProgram.DiversionProgramID);
```